# Can I initialize a PHP variable with a concat assignment operator?

Tags: php, concatenation

Will initializing a PHP variable with the concatenation assignment operator (`.=`) cause problems? I'm in a situation where a variable may or may not have already been created, but if it is, I don't want to overwrite it.

If I do this:

```
$a .= "World!";
```

and `$a` already exists, will it blow things up? I don't want to have to do the following every single time:

```
if(!isset($a)){
    $a = "World!";
} else {
    $a .= "World!";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it'll issue warnings. `$a .= 'foo'` is the equivalent of `$a = $a . 'foo'`. You're ACCESSING the variable before it's been defined

```
   $a = $a . 'foo';
1.       ^---read value from undefined variable 'a'
2.             ^---append string 'foo';
3.  ^---assign value to new variable 'a'
```

Since PHP can't time travel, step #1 will issue a "undefined variable" warning.

Comment: Since this is a known and expected warning, could I just do `@$a .= "World!";`

Comment: no. using `@` is the programming equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you". it's VERY POOR programming practice.

Comment: PHP can't time travel, but apparently [C can](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Answer (score 3):

Try it and see?

```
unset($a);
$a .= 'World!'; // Notice: Undefined variable

$a = 123;
$a.= 'World!';  //$a is now '123World!';

$a = null;
$a .= 'World!';  //$a is 'World!';
```

A [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is a useful operator.  (as comments suggests)

```
$a = (isset($a)) ? $a .= 'World!' : $a = 'World!'; // Will avoid a notice.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could initialise $a if it's not set like this

```
isset($a) || $a = '';
$a .= "World!";
```

or like this

```
$a = (isset($a) ? $a : '') . 'World!';
```